# How to include all the dataset variables into the model

Tags: r, sas, regression

I am wondering, if SAS can include all the dataset variables into a regression model without typing them all. I used R before, and I want something like:

```
model <- lm(y ~ ., data = d)
```

but in SAS.

Comment: I think you can use a variable list if they are all in order: e.g. `firstvar--lastvar`

Comment: Sometimes you can use a colon, like this: `(drop=_:)` will drop all variables starting with an underline

Comment: I know in some situations `_all_` is used to refer to all variables, so that might be worth a try.

Comment: `_all_` would be allowed wherever a variable list is allowed (the `model` statement does allow this), but it wouldn't work because the dependent variable would be included as an independent variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, SAS doesn't have an simple way to do this.

You could put all of your independent variables into a macro variable then reference the macro variable in your model statement:

```
proc sql;
select name into :ivars separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns
where libname eq 'WORK'      /*library name        */
  and memname eq 'YOURDATA'  /*data set name       */
  and name    ne 'DEPVAR'    /*exlude dep variable */ ;
quit;

proc reg;
  model DEPVAR = &ivars;
run;
```

Comment: That's the way I would do it.  As noted in comment above, you would need to exclude dependent variable from the list

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way, but I have not tried it.

```
proc reg data=d;
model y = _all_;
run;
```

Since regression model by default can be built using only numeric variables you can use this.

```
proc reg data=d;
model y = _num_;
run;
```

If you have a character variable, convert it to a Weight of Evidence transformed variable so that they will be converted to numeric and then you can use the above code.